# Webpack "publicPath" "auto" with subfolder

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I'm currently using webpack to serve assets from `localhost:8000`, these are being loaded in a "host" page on `localhost:3000`. How do I serve these webpack assets from a subfolder but maintain them being served from same the webpack server domain/port?

**SCENARIO 1**

```
// config
output: {
    publicPath: 'auto'
}

// result
https://localhost:8000/some-file.js // the port is correct but missing subfolder
```

**SCENARIO 2**

```
// config
output: {
    publicPath: '/subfolder'
}

// result
https://localhost:3000/subfolder/some-file.js // the port now becomes the host which I don't want
```

**SOLUTION ????**

```
// config
output: {
    publicPath: ???? // How can I make this use the "auto" domain but add a path prefix
}

// result
https://localhost:8000/subfolder/some-file.js
```